# Connecting to database which is different from I specified in spring XML

Tags: eclipse, spring

```
<bean 
    id="DBDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" 
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc\:mysql\://pc123456\:3306/reven"/>
    <property name="username" value="reven"/>
    <property name="password" value="23454"/>
</bean>
```

this is my code but the eclipse connecting some other database and giving below error

> java.lang.AssertionError: Failed due to Error:
>   org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate
>   operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL
>   [???]; SQL state [28000]; error code [1045]; Access denied for user
>   'ules'@'PC234333' (using password: YES); nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'ules'@'PC234333' (using
>   password: YES)

Comment: Please, check if you have bean with "dataSource" name, or ensure that entity manager (if you use one) uses appropriate data source bean.

Comment: @nndru there is no problem in data source name and entity manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have wrong url, put the url like this

```
 <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://pc123456:3306/xxx"/>
```

Where `xxx` is the db name of MySql.

And make sure with the given user name you are able to login in the MySql db